# How to set a NeumannValue on a given ElementMarker on the boundary of a mesh?

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

How can one apply a `NeumannValue` on an `ElementMarker` on the boundary of an `ElementMesh` for a mesh already defined (i.e. with `ElementMarkers` being defined as 1,2,3 etc)?

It is not so clear what `ElementMarker`s actually correspond to, for example it is possible to have boundary elements with the same label as mesh elements.

Comment: I can certainly help you with this. But before I do that I am curious to know how you tried to search for it in the documentation?

Comment: I'd like to improve the searching.

Comment: @user21 Basically I tried going through all the FE documentation (searching for NeumannValue, and BoundaryElementMarker). I did searches over the Stackexchange site, as well as in general on Google, but didn't really find any examples that fit.

Comment: OK, got it, thanks. Hang in a few more minutes while I prepare an answer.

Comment: Ah ok, I see why you are interested. One problem is it seems that when one searches in a combined way NeumannValue and BoundaryElementMarker together then one gets very few search hits. The other problem is the search of the FE typically comes to the very long tutorials which you then have to search inside of. Great if this helps you improve the searching

Comment: One problem is that BoundaryElementMarker does not exist. The other problem is that `ElementMarker` is not a system context symbol. So it can not be used in the system level documentation like that of `NeumannValue` and I am not sure what I can do about that. I have tried to improve the search results a bit but I am not 100% sure this would have helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
```

To illustrate the process of making use of ElementMarkers in a simulation we create a simple mesh that has ElementMarkers in the MeshElements, BoundaryElements and "PointElements".

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> {{1.293, 0.228}, {1., 0.}, {0.94, 0.342}, {1.293, 
     0.}, {1.215, 0.442}, {2., 0.}, {1.879, 0.684}}, 
  "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 
       6}, {1, 6, 7}, {1, 7, 5}, {1, 5, 3}}, {66, 66, 66, 44, 44, 
      44}]},
  "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{3, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {4, 
       6}, {6, 1}, {6, 7}, {7, 5}, {5, 3}}, {11, 22, 33, 33, 22, 44, 
      55, 55}]},
  "PointElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, \
{7}}, {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}]}]
```

Visualize the mesh and the IDs of the nodes.

```
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], 
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Brown]]]
```

[image]

Visualize the mesh with markers in the "MeshElements" in blue, the markers in the "BoundaryElements" inn red and the markers in the "PointElements" in brown.

```
Show[
 mesh["Wireframe"],
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]],
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
   "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Red]],
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Brown]]
 ]
```

[image]

Note that the boundary edge from node 6 to node 7 has a marker of 44 while the mesh element made up of nodes {1,6,7} also has a marker of 44 set.

As an example a Poisson type equation with a right hand side that depends on the markers in the "MeshElements" is used. If a mesh element has a marker of 44 then 10 is used as the value of the right hand side. In all other cases 1 is used. Also a NeumannValue of -1 is set on all edges that have a marker set to 44. A DirichletCondtion is set on the point that has an ElementMarker of 1.

```
ufun = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 
    If[ElementMarker == 44, 10, 1] + 
     NeumannValue[-1, ElementMarker == 44], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, ElementMarker == 1]}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

Visualize the solution.

```
Plot3D[ufun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

[image]

Note that the fact that both the mesh elements and boundary elements make use of a marker with number 44 does not matter. ElementMarkers used in coefficients like the If statement operate on the markers present in the mesh elements. References to ElementMarkers in NeumannValue refer to markers on "BoundaryElements" and makers in DirichletCondition refer to markers in "PointElements"

Comment: Super this is really helpful!

Comment: @Dunlop I have put it in the documentation, though in the [ElementMesh generation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html)

Comment: Thanks again! I think I got a bit confused with the labelling for BoundaryElement etc. I see the problem though that if these terms are not system context symbols then it is difficult to write documentation for them

Comment: Should I edit the question so that your response makes more sense and it would be more useful to others and hopefully easier to find?

Comment: @Dunlop,I don't know. What do you think?

Comment: I will try to make the question a bit clearer and hopefully this makes it more useful. If it is too confusing let me know and I can change back.

Comment: @Dunlop I made a few more changes. I hope you do not mind. If you do not like it we can roll them back.

Comment: All good! Many thanks